# Next without For compile error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to VBA and am working on a project which will display all current users who have a particular file open (MS Access). I am trying to populate a listbox with the computer name info but am getting an error when I try to run the button command.rs.Fields(0) is the only field I need as it is the computer name. I just need a list of all computer names connected.

```
Sub ShowUserRosterMultipleUsers()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
    , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}"

    'While Not rs.EOF
        'Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1), _
        'rs.Fields(2), rs.Fields(3)
        'rs.MoveNext
    'Wend

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        With List73
            .AddItem rs.Fields(0)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: As the error message rightfully states, `Next` is not the right way to end a `Do While` loop.

Comment: Your Do While should be `Loop` not `Next`

Comment: do you mean like Loop While rs.EOF?

Comment: No, Change the `Next` to `Loop`

Comment: Thanks! sorry I was confused. I also changed my listbox to a Value List. When I run the command, it seems to hang. Did I create some endless loop?

Comment: Yes you did. Add `rs.MoveNext` at the end of the loop.

Comment: THANKS!! got it working and learned a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub ShowUserRosterMultipleUsers()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
    , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}"

    'While Not rs.EOF
        'Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1), _
        'rs.Fields(2), rs.Fields(3)
        'rs.MoveNext
    'Wend

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        With List73
            .AddItem rs.Fields(0)
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: without moving the rs you're going to hang the process.

Comment: @GavinP The question says hes trying to populate a listbox and was getting an error. The error has been fixed. The infinite loop is off subject from his question.